# Gradient descent loop producing NaN in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I'm running a gradient descent loop to minimize a function, but my parameter vector w is calculated as NaN while it should be a numerical vector. This means that at some point the function is going to infinity, but I'm not sure why.

Here is the loop. The data is a data set of students nested within schools so first the program loops over each school, and the second loop performs the gradient descent. The y variable is a test score measure and the x vector contains categorical student demographic characteristics and school characteristics, and a few percentages such as poverty and gender rate. The key computation is g, which computes the gradient, and I believe this is where something is going to infinity leading to the NaN result instead of a numerical vector. The g result immediately outputs as NaN when it should be numerical.

```
w_old = rand(28, length(tr_indexes));
tolerance = 1e-6;
maxIter = 1000;
stepsize = .1;
grid = zeros(10,1);
w = w_old;
u = rand(28,length(tr_indexes));
theta = rand(10,28);

       for t = 1:T
            t_trainx = trainx(:, tr_indexes(t):tr_indexes(t+1)-1 );
            t_trainy = trainy(tr_indexes(t):tr_indexes(t+1)-1)';
            s = length(t_trainx);
            for j = 1:maxIter
                w_old(:, t) =  w(:,t);
                v= theta*u(:,t);
                g = ((2/s)*((t_trainy-(w(:,t)'*t_trainx + v'*theta*t_trainx))*t_trainx')' + 2*lambda*w(:,t))
                w(:,t)= w_old(:,t) - stepsize*g;
                u(:,t)= w(:,t) + theta'*v;
                if norm(abs(w(:,t)-w_old(:,t))) < tolerance;
                break
                end
            end
        end
```

Can anyone suggest what aspects of this code are leading to this NaN result?

Comment: What is `s`? If you suspect `w` goes to infinity, it can be due to `s` as a denominator

Comment: s is the number of observations in each school (length(t_trainx)). This is never zero, so should not be resulting in w going to infinity. thank for the input though.

Comment: Have you tried using the Matlab [debugger](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html)? Set a breakpoint in the line where you compute `g` and examine the RHS quantities.